# Can a duplicate detection job be run for a single rule?

Tags: duplicates, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Within Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015, is it possible to create A Duplicate Detection Job which runs only for a single Duplicate Detection Rule (or a subset of the available rules) for a given Entity?

I am trying to identify duplicates which exist on the basis of a specific rule only, so any alternative solution would also be welcome, for example if there is some way to filter the results of a Duplicate Detection Job on the basis of which rule(s) caused a particular record to appear in the results.

Ideally I'd like a UI-only solution to this, but would consider a code-based approach if that is the only way.

Comment: Do you want a UI-only solution or is code a viable option ?

Comment: UI would be preferable please - I will edit question accordingly.

Comment: I don't think this is possible either from the UI or by code. It is either all or nothing. If it is just a one time run, you can un-publish the rules that you don't want to run.

Comment: Yeah, I did consider un-publishing the rules I wasn't interested in, but just wondered if I could achieve this without doing that, as un-publishing rules in a production environment might not be acceptable.